Nginx configuration not working correctly with gunicorn
I have a Django app hosted on a GCP instance that has an external IP, the Django is running using Gunicorn on port 8000, when accessing the Django using EXTERNAL_IP:8000 the site works perfectly, but when trying to access the Django using EXTERNAL_IP:18000 the site doesn't work(This site can’t be reached), how to fix the Nginx configuration?
All the IPs will be replaced with the domain once testing is done.
In Django settings: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
gunicorn_config.py
command = "/home/path/venv/bin/gunicorn"
pythonpath = "/home/path/venv/bin/python"
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = 3

supervisor.conf
[program: procurement]
directory = /home/path/
command = /home/path/venv/bin/gunicorn namet_system.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
user = user
stdout_logfile = /home/path/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

nginx_config
upstream procurement_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

map $http_origin $cors_origin {
    default "null";
}

server {
    server_name LB_IP1 LB_IP2 EXTERNAL_IP;
    listen 18000 ;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http")
    {
      set $do_redirect_to_https "true";
    }
    if ($do_redirect_to_https = "true")
    {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }


    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $http_x_forwarded_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://procurement_server;
    }
}

